# ¿Como mantengo siempre una conexion webscoket con Python?

Tags: python, websocket

Estoy usando esto como ejemplo para mi websocket:

```
import websocket
try:
    import thread
except ImportError:
    import _thread as thread
import time

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")

def on_open(ws):
    def run(*args):
        for i in range(3):
            time.sleep(1)
            ws.send("Hello %d" % i)
        time.sleep(1)
        ws.close()
        print("thread terminating...")
    thread.start_new_thread(run, ())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://echo.websocket.org/",
                              on_message = on_message,
                              on_error = on_error,
                              on_close = on_close)
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()
```

Pero luego de un par de segundos mi conexion se cierra y esta no vuelve a conectarse, ¿Existe alguna forma de reconexion en caso de que falle por x razon el websocket?

Comment: Tu mismo estás cerrando el websocket haciendo `ws.close()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu mismo estás cerrando el websocket haciendo `ws.close()`, mira el código para cuando se abre una conexión de WebSockets:

1. Se envía con `ws.send()` los datos: `"Hola 1"` ,`"Hola 2"` , `"Hola 3"` por medio del webSocket, con un segundo de tiempo entre cada mensaje provisto por `time.sleep(1)`.
2. Esperamos un segundo con `time.sleep(1)`.
3. **Cerramos** el websocket con `ws.close()`

### UPDATE

Si miras [la documentación](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html), puedes ver cómo uno de los parámetros por defecto del constructor del WebSocket es `ping_timeout=20`, puedes obtener más información de esto [acá](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#websockets.protocol.WebSocketCommonProtocol), de donde resalto:

> Once the connection is open, a Ping frame is sent every ping_interval
> seconds. This serves as a keepalive. It helps keeping the connection
> open, especially in the presence of proxies with short timeouts on
> inactive connections. Set ping_interval to None to disable this
> behavior.
>
> If the corresponding Pong frame isn’t received within ping_timeout
> seconds, the connection is considered unusable and is closed with code
> 1011. This ensures that the remote endpoint remains responsive. Set ping_timeout to None to disable this behavior.

Es posible que lo que necesites es hacer que tu cliente siga estos protocolos, sin embargo, pueden ser muchas cosas lo que está afectando a tu webSocket y haciendo que se cierre, te recomiendo que busques en la documentación como imprimir el código del error bajo el cual se cierra el webSocket. Te recuerdo que el webSocket puede ser cerrado tanto por el cliente como el servidor, un buen primer paso sería descubrir quien está cerrando el canal.

Es una buena práctica también en el cliente hacer protocolos de reconexión en caso de que la conexión se caiga, dependiendo de  tu aplicación, esto podría ser suficiente.

Comment: Sii, eso me olvido decir que esa parte la elimine, pero igual, gracias jajaj. Pero aun así la conexion se desconecta despues de un rato (Elimine lo de ws.close) en estos casos existe una forma de reconexion?

Comment: Te actualicé la respuesta, espero que te sirva, suerte programando.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!